# How do I remove the page listing menu in the header in the Twenty Ten Theme?

Tags: theme-options

How do I  remove the page listing menu in the header? I would like just the choosen header picture to show up without a listing of all of the pages on the site listed underneath.

Also at the very top or the page it displays the domain and  title above the header. What is the best way to eliminate that and just have the header picture hug the top of the screen?

I and using the free theme Twenty Ten. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a simple fix and that is removing line 103 in the themes header.php file but next time you update the theme it will return so to make you change permanent and still enjoy the updates first Create a child theme and then overwrite the header.php file in your child theme.

its sound hard but its really not:

First create a directory in your themes directory eg `my_theme`

Then create a new file named style.css and add this to it.

```
/*
Theme Name: Twentyten Child
Description: Child theme for the twentyeleven theme 
Author: Your name here
Template: twentyten
version: 0.1
*/`

@import url("../twentyten/style.css");
```

and last copy the header.php file from the `twentyten` directory to your `my_theme` and then remove line 103 from it (in your new theme directory).

Comment: line 103 in the header.php is "?>" without the quotes. When I deleted and saved it the site doesnt load properly any ideas?

Comment: @brandon What version of Twenty Ten are you using? In the latest version line 103 is `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>`

Comment: I am using version theme version 1.4. I found the line you mentioned - it was line 205 in my file. I am using a Program called Notepad++ to open header.php- is that my issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: Rebooted and redownloaded header.php - that line was on 103 as expected. I removed the line uploaded and it worked Thanks you to all for your help!